# Rendering a partial view in Layout and declare a controller for it in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have the following scenario

```
 @model CashUnited.Models.HomeViewModel   
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>@ViewData["Title"] - test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <partial name="_Header" model="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model)"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

my partial view Code

```
<select>
@{
   foreach (string item in Model.companiesLst)
   {
      <option value="@item">@item</option>
   }
}
```

How and where I can Fill **Model.companiesLst** from the controller? I can't seem to figure it out in asp.net Core

Comment: Have you looked into the Html.Partial or Html.RenderPartial Helpers? The documentation on them might be useful for you. I believe you set up either an ActionResult or PartialViewResult on your controller side to set the values for the partial view's model.

Comment: I found the answer by using the components in ASP.net core

Answer (score 0):

You have to create/get instances of your model and then pass it to the main view like this:

```
public ActionResult GetItems() {
    var items = this.itemsService.GetItems();

    return this.View(items);
}
```

Where variable with name *items* is your model which contains the property *companiesList*.

*The parent view:*

```
@model CashUnited.Models.HomeViewModel   
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>@ViewData["Title"] - test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   @await Html.PartialAsync("_Header", Model)
 </body>
</html>
```

*The partial view:*

```
@model CashUnited.Models.HomeViewModel

<select>
@{
   foreach (string item in Model.companiesLst)
   {
      <option value="@item">@item</option>
   }
} 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470112/6694514. It seems to fix a similar issue to the one you are having.

Comment: Link only answers should be avoided.  If this is a duplicate, mark it as such.